# Does svn move command also moves files within directory?

Tags: svn

I've used `svn move` on dir that contains sub dirs and files. But under status I see,

```
D dir
D file1
D file2
etc

A + dir
```

But I don't see files or subfolders. So before I commit I wonder if `svn move` moves also files subfolders, is that plus sign for that?

[image]

Comment: If you have `/one/two/three` there's no physical way to move `two` and keep `three` intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`svn move`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) does move the files and folders.  I've never really liked the output of [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) when moving directories, but the `A  +` is supposed to be showing you that it's preserving history.  Replicating this locally, I get similar output:

```
$ svn st
D       dir-a
D       dir-a/file2.txt
D       dir-a/file3.txt
D       dir-a/file1.txt
A  +    dir-b
```

Using the `--verbose` or `-v` option, you can see more:

```
$ svn st -v
                 0        0  ?           .
D                1        1 jszakmeister dir-a
D                1        1 jszakmeister dir-a/file2.txt
D                1        1 jszakmeister dir-a/file3.txt
D                1        1 jszakmeister dir-a/file1.txt
A  +             -        1 jszakmeister dir-b
   +             -        1 jszakmeister dir-b/file2.txt
   +             -        1 jszakmeister dir-b/file3.txt
   +             -        1 jszakmeister dir-b/file1.txt
```

This is essentially telling you that the files where moved as well.  The `+` is showing you that the history was maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `svn move` also moves the files and subfolders.

Comment: Why don't I see subfiles and folders in Added list when I do svn status? I see Add only on top directories.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze what about `svn status --verbose`?